# Trying to convert a HashMap into a scala ListMap

Tags: java, scala, securesocial

So, there is a particular class, which I am overriding in a certain framework (not relevant, but it is the SecureSocial framework for Play). The method I am overriding has the signature:

In Scala:

```
override val providers : scala.collection.immutable.ListMap[scala.Predef.String, securesocial.core.IdentityProvider] = { /* compiled code */ }
```

So, I simply wrote it as:

```
@Override
ListMap<String, IdentityProvider> providers() { ... }
```

The problem is that the only thing I can do with `ListMap` from Java is:

```
new ListMap<>();
```

Which is not very useful. The `Map` that I want to override is being injected via a DI, and what I have is a `java.util.HashMap`. So, my method is looking like this:

```
@Override
ListMap<String, IdentityProvider> providers() {
    Map<String, IdentityProvider> providerMap = this.providerMap;
    toScalaListMap(providerMap);
}
```

Of course, `toScalaListMap` does not exist. How do I go about writing it? I've tried searching online and looking at the scala documentation, but given my zero knowledge of Scala as of now, I don't know where to begin. I am adding the `securesocial` tag in this question just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I got around this is to use something like this:

```
return (ListMap<String, IdentityProvider>)new ListMap<String, IdentityProvider>()
            .newBuilder()
            .$plus$eq(new Tuple2<>("provider1", provider1))
            .$plus$eq(new Tuple2<>("provider2", provider2))
            .result();
```

Where `Tuple2` is essentially `scala.Tuple2`. It is ugly, but it works!

Answer (score 1):

There is an `asScala` method available on Java collections detailed in the scala docs [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConverters%24). Simply calling it on your collection should do the conversion for you.

Comment: But I don't think I can access any method called `asScala` from within a .java file. The compiler will not detect this method.

Comment: Ah, okay, sorry. I had the situation reversed; I thought you were working in scala and trying to import a java collection. My mistake.